# Why ternary operator is not "working" in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have following statement:

```
val visibility = if (itemView.img_playstore.visibility == View.VISIBLE)  View.GONE else View.VISIBLE
```

And another:

```
val visibility : Int = itemView.img_playstore.visibility == View.VISIBLE ?  View.GONE : View.VISIBLE
```

The first one is OK, but for the second one, I am getting the following message: **Type mismatch. Required Int. Found Boolean.**

What would be the reason for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is simple: There's *no ternary operator* in Kotlin. Your `if/else` from the first snippet is probably the best alternative as it's an *expression* in Kotlin (other than Java e.g.).

```
val cond: Boolean = true
val visibility: Int = if (cond) 2 else 3
```

Also `when` can be used:

```
val cond: Boolean = ...
val visibility: Int = when {
    cond -> 2
    else -> 3
}
```

Or like this:

```
val visibility: Int = when (cond) {
    true -> 2
    false -> 3
}
```

Many ways, but no ternary operator...

Comment: Yeah I missed it first too. But the `if/else` thingy is actually more readable than using single characters as `:` and `?` in the ternary operator. The great thing is: `if` and `when` are expressions :)

Answer (score 4):

As [@s1m0nw1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46435992/8073652) mentioned, there is no ternary operator. One great way which I found with extension function and `Boolean` is this:

```
infix fun <T> Boolean.then(param: T): T? = if (this) param else null
```

You can use this extension function as below:

```
setBackgroundColor(isHighPriority() then RED ?: WHITE)
```